# pagination works but it doesn't go to next page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

i have added pagination on my site, everything is fine but whenever i click next it will go to same page url/dataload2.php?page=0. This is my php code, i think it is something wrong in calculations or looping, thank you for any help.

EDIT: some more code added

```
    <?php

include 'conn.php';
$num_rec_per_page=2;

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

$sql = "SELECT * from crewlist ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
```

and

```
 <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM crewlist"; 
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

    echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
    }; 
    echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
    ?>
```

EDIT: update syntax

```
 <?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM crewlist"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
<?php
echo "<a href='dataload2.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs here. Your connection could be MySQLi_ (seeing `$conn->query($sql)`), while you're using `mysql_` in the other. Those different APIs don't intermix.

Comment: changed syntax to mysqli, still don't work

Comment: update your question with the new code you're now using then.

Comment: sorry for late response :P

Comment: `mysqli_query($sql);` requires db connection `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: it works thank you, put it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your edit:

```
$rs_result = mysqli_query($sql);
```

- `mysqli_query()` requires a db connection be passed as the first parameter

Change your code to read as:

```
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

*and you'll be good to go.*

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Plus, do read up on [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) as you could get hit by an [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

- Best to be on the safe side ;-)

Additional references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php